# Thread synchronization in WinCE

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, windows-ce, thread-synchronization

I have faced with a problem of threads synchronization. My presenter analyzes some sensors and update UI form. I moved updating code into separate thread. It works fine, but if the user stops presenter when it is updating the view, the software freezes - I found that it happens when view.UpdateUI working (it just set some labels using Invoke). Where my problem is? I use compact framework 3.5 and Windows CE 5

```
using System.Threading;

class MyPresenter
{
  UserControl view;

  private Thread thread;
  private ManualResetEvent cancelEvent;

  public void Start()
  {
    cancelEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    thread = new Thread(UpdateView) { IsBackground = true };
    thread.Start();
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    if (thread != null) {
      cancelEvent.Set();
      thread.Join();
      thread = null;
    }
  }

  private void UpdateView()
  {
    while (cancelEvent.WaitOne(1000, false) == false) {
      // analyze something
      view.UpdateUI(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your background thread is blocked calling your UI (via `Control.Invoke`), and then your UI thread is blocked calling your Stop method with its `thread.Join()` you've got yourself a classic fatal embrace.  You should get rid of the Join and instead have the background thread raise one last event / notification when the Stop completes so the UI can deal with that (enable/disable buttons etc).

Comment: Do you mean I should set some event (cancelledEvent) at the end of UpdateView function and replace thread.Join to cancelledEvent.WaitOne? But WaitOne will also block the thread. Is there any difference?

Comment: What you **cannot** do is call Thread.Join within the UI thread.  You could remove that one call and be fine.  But I assumed the reason it was there was because the UI wanted to know about (wait for) the background handler's completion.  If you need that functionality, have the background handler send another notification just before it exits.  You don't show your marshalling code, but consider using BeginInvoke for this call so you the background handler isn't waiting around for the notification to be handled.

Comment: Actually my `view.UpdateUI` function called `Invoke(...)` method, I have replaced that to `BeginInvoke(...)` and `thread.Join` to `canceledEvent.WaitOne`. It seems to be OK now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't update the UI thread directly from within a worker thread. Use a delegate instead. 
For example: [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)